# Is it possible to do type narrowing in case that `str in obj` infers `str` is of type `keyof obj`?

Tags: typescript, typeguards

Take this code as an example:

```js
function isKeyOf<T extends {}>(
  key: string, // this: string,
  obj: T,
): key is keyof T {
  return key in obj;
}
```

This works fine, but what if I want to do chaining (like an extension method)

In usage like this:

```js
let key: string;
// ...
if (key.isKeyOf(obj)) {
  obj[key] = value;
  // ...
}
```

I have to do something like

```js
// declare global {
interface /*Custom*/String {
  isKeyOf<T extends object>(obj: T): this is { value: keyof T }
}
// }
```

But if I try:

```js
CustomString.prototype.isKeyOf = function<T extends {}>(obj: T): this is keyof T {
  return this in obj;
}
```

TS compiler won't let me use `this` in type guard functions.

How to implement type narrowing in case that `str in obj` infers `str` is of type `keyof obj` ?

Comment: It's widely considered bad practice to extend native prototypes unless you're polyfilling.  Since I presume you don't want to talk about that, could you [edit] the question to remove that aspect of it?  Make up your own interface/class and extend its prototype and we can then work on how to get `this`-like behavior, if you want.

Comment: Please ask a single question per post; the question at the end should probably be removed.

Comment: Assuming you [edit] like I've asked in my previous comments, then [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WPgLLm) is how I'd do it.  You just need to merge in the method signature and then the implementation can be wider (and return a `boolean`).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining. If not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jcalz example, which solves the original question:

**You don't need to specify type guard at implementation, just return `boolean` as normally what it does.**

For a better approach committed by @jcalz, please see: [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WPgLLm)

Here's a personal demo. 
***NOTE**: Extending native prototypes can be a bad practice, do not use unless you know the disadvantages*

```js
// declaration & implementation
// # extension.ts
declare global {
  interface String {
    isKeyOf<T extends {}>(obj: T): this is keyof T
  }
}

// just leave type guard blank in implementation.
String.prototype.isKeyOf = function <T extends {}>(this: string, obj: T) {
  return Object.keys(obj).includes(this)
}

export {}

// # foo.ts (import this before any usage)
// import './extension'

const obj = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }

let key = 'a'
if (key in obj) {
  obj[key] = 4
  // expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ a: number; b: number; c: number; }'
}

if (key.isKeyOf(obj)) {
  obj[key] = 4
}
```